# Angular2: Display 2 arrays as key value pair in reverse with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have 2 arrays for example

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I display these as key value pairs in reverse order using *ngFor?
Like E:5 D:4......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index syntax of *ngFor. this is [document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) of *ngFor.
And don't forget to use array.reverse for the target array.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testArray; let i = index">
    {{ testArray[i] }} : {{ testArray2[i] }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do use `Array.prototype.reverse()` method to reverse the values and then you can get it like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let str of strArr; let i=index">{{str}} : {{numArr[i]}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  strArr: Array<string> = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  numArr: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  constructor() {
    this.strArr.reverse(); // reverse the values ["E", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
    this.numArr.reverse(); // reverse the values [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  }
}
```

[Demo @Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zMFh2FCZt2cM1xtiTVmj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to  try writing a component function that takes in two arrays and returns an array of sorted key value pairs. Do all your basic error checking in your function, and then simply call your function in your view similar to this:

```
*ngFor="let keypair of getKeyPairs(charArray, intArray)"
```

The sorting pipes from angular1 were removed from angular 2 so you will have to implement that sorting yourself.